# html5 video tag src type

Tags: html5-video

Hello
I am using video tag of html5.  But I have this problem: since my web server doesnt have direct access to file container server, I have to read files with php first and then send to web server. For example with images I do the following:

```
<img src="getImage.php?id=123" />
```

where getImage.php is something like this:

```
<?php
$id=$_GET['id'];
$file='//ip/somepath/image'.$id.'.jpg';
echo file_get_contents($file);
?>
```

This works great with images tag, but i try with video tag and it doenst work on firefox 3.6, but works on Google Chrome:

```
<video id="movie" preload controls>
 <source src="databank/getVideo.php?video_id=123" />
</video>
```

......getVideo.php.....

```
echo file_get_contents('videfile.ogv');
```

Any idea how to solve this problem? Thanks you all

Comment: did you try putting "header("content-type: image/jpeg");" at the top?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the server sends the ogv file with a supported MIME type. 
Something like just add into ".htaccess" file following:

```
AddType audio/ogg oga ogg
AddType video/ogg ogv
```